# Bind view to localStorage value

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm building a mobile application (with ionic) which will make a http request to update the view. But I want to display old value while an ajax call gets the fresh data.
My idea is to use localStorage. I will show old data from localStorage and once ajax call brings back new data I want to update localStorage. So I've tried to use ngStorage. But it does not work at all.
here is what the code looks like:
Controller

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngStorage'])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $localStorage){
  $scope.$storage = $localStorage;
})
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.10/ngStorage.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      {{$storage.x}}
    </div>
```

and Local Storage is this :

```
Storage {x: "This should be attached to HTML"}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for data binding

```
angular.element($window).on('storage', function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'my-storage') {
      $rootScope.$apply();
    }
  });
```

You can wrap this in a factory

```
app.factory("LS", function($window, $rootScope) {
  angular.element($window).on('storage', function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'my-storage') {
      $rootScope.$apply();
    }
  });
  return {
    setData: function(val) {
      $window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.setItem('my-storage', val);
      return this;
    },
    getData: function() {
      return $window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.getItem('my-storage');
    }
  };
});
```